# ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined - on using handlebarsJs version 2.0.0

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js, amd

I am using requirejs v2.1.6 for loading libraries like jquery, jquery mobile , handlebarjs and other javascript libraries. I am using handlebarsJS version 2.0.0 runtime.

```
paths : {

        text : 'lib/require/text',
        jquery : 'lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min',
        jquerymobile : 'lib/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min',
        Handlebars : 'lib/handlebars/handlebars.runtime-v2.0.0'
}
```

While loading the pre-compiled templates,

```
var template = Handlebars.templates['loginTemplate'];
```

i am getting the error

```
Reference Error: Handlebars is not defined


var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebar...
```

Comment: Is the code that loads the pre-compiled templates wrapped in a `define()` where Handlebars is specified as a dependency?

Comment: yes, the templates are wrapped in define() & the Handlebars is specified i the dependency.